# xorg fails to start on freebsd even after installing nvidia and drm-kmod

Tags: xorg, freebsd, nvidia, gpu

So i decided to use freebsd as my daily driver but the xorg seems not to work so first of all when i tried startx for the first time (i installed the nvidia drivers) it gave

> (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer mode

Heres the full log file - https://pastebin.com/sKCsm2Nn

Then i tried `nvidia-xconfig` then it gave me this-

> (EE) no screens found(EE)

Heres the full log - https://pastebin.com/5kXndP8J
I have a lenovo flex 2-14 heres my gpu specifications-

> vgapci0@pci0:0:2:0:     class=0x030000 card=0x397817aa chip=0x0a168086 rev=0x0b hdr=0x00
> vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
> device     = 'Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller'
> class      = display
> --
> vgapci1@pci0:4:0:0:     class=0x030200 card=0x381717aa chip=0x114010de rev=0xa1 hdr=0x00
> vendor     = 'NVIDIA Corporation'
> device     = 'GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]'
> class      = display

I have installed the `nvidia-driver-390-390.138_1, drm-kmod(i915kms.ko)`.

Comment: You are required to post your minimal, relevant information here and not a link to other sites like pastebin. [ask]

Comment: How did you install xorg and nvidia? Did you use `pkg`? Did you make any changes to Xorg.conf? What is in `.xinitrc`? I *think* you no longer need to run `nvidia-xconfig` as FreeBSD auto detects it but I could be wrong.

Comment: As ive said earlier without the xorg.conf it give me `(EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer mode`

Comment: meh i switched to nomadbsd instead

Comment: Well, nomad bsd is pre-configured FreeBSD.

Comment: Everything worked fine in nomadbsd anyways thanks for the help rob

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using 12.2-RELEASE . There's a lot of checklist to ask .

- drm-kmod is broken https://twitter.com/vermaden/status/1321375859429773312 , you need to build it from port
- you need to add user to video group by `# pw group mod video -m your_username`
- there's also option to switch 12.1-RELEASE , or CURRENT
- adding `# sysrc kld_list+="/boot/modules/i915kms.ko"`
- ofc , after installing nvidia-driver properly use kldload nvidia-modeset then reboot

Hope either one of these help

Answer (score -1):

you have to use xorg.conf for nvidia

just take the "BusID" generated by X -configure from /root/xorg.conf for your device and use it with /etc/X11/xorg.conf

where BusID is your BusID if not device 5:0:0

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Device0"
Driver "nvidia"
VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
BusID "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection
```

your /etc/rc.conf should look like this "if you use lightdm otherwise ignore the lightdm line"

```
linux_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
hald_enable="YES"
lightdm_enable="YES"
kld_list="nvidia nvidia-modeset linux"
```

Comment: It's wrong to load both `nvidia` **and  `nvidia-modeset`.